# SQl Loader using Python

Tags: python-2.7, sql-loader

I see that SQL Loader is behaving quite weird.

I have executed a command on my Terminal(Linux) as

```
sqlldr username/password@XXXX control=xxx.ctl
```

The above command didnot produces any errors:

```
Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:             4
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0
```

but when i used this statement inside python script:

```
subprocess.call('sqlldr USERNAME/PASSWORD3@XXX control=XXX.ctl', shell=True)
```

i see no records are been loaded into the target table:

```
Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:             0
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0
```

The concern is that when i run the SQL loader command in commandline it behaves normal, but not within the python script.Any suggestions please..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as I believe you need the USERID= before the login info:

```
subprocess.call('sqlldr userid=USERNAME/PASSWORD3@XXX control=XXX.ctl', shell=True)
```